# Next JS - how to set random number as id in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I fix the error below?

```
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

Here's my code.

```
export class Card {                
    constructor(props) {              
        this.id = Math.random();    
    }
}
```

If I change the id to a static number like below, the error goes away but I need the id to be a random number.

```
export class Card {                
    constructor(props) {              
        this.id = 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check when you're on the client side.

1. The easiest way to find out is to use `componentDidMount` and set a state by creating the random number. In functional one, `useEffect` will be used.
2. Another way is checking `typeof window === 'undefined'`. If it's `false`, so `window` exists and you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using Math.random() in the constructor will be invoked on a server and in the browser causing a mismatch in rendered markup.

You can Update the random in the componentDidMount or useEffect,

Refer.. [Incorrect rendering of a component when using Math.random in setState in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186584/incorrect-rendering-of-a-component-when-using-math-random-in-setstate-in-react-c)

```
export class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: 3,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      id: Math.random(),
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.id);
    return this.state.id;
  }
}
```